# Build a workflow when new list item is created

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow

I am using SharePoint Online and trying to create a workflow using flow. But not sure if it's even possible or if my skillset is just to low.

I would like to build something that will email based on the value in a column. 
Something like, ***IF value*** is "X" then send email to "Y" ; if value is "A" then send email to "B".

Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is possible. you need to develop some basic logic in your workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible and it is really easy.

In SPO Library click on Flow and click **Create a flow**:

[image]

**Click See more and select When a new file is added in SharePoint, complete a custom action:** (trigger will be automatically set) or you can create flow with different trigger (next picture) (timer - like once per day/ when file eidted,....)

[image]

or

[image]

After this in flow you can work with file properties - depends if you have already loeaded file properties with trigger or loading all with **Get- List Items** function ald load items from list (can be based on some filter)

[image]

After this create **Condition function** where you will set the condition and in the states you can use **Office 365 - Send Email** function

*If yo are working with more than one file/item there will be "*Apply to each*" loop*, otherwise you will work only with the Condition.

In the condition set, what you want. After this **Send Email**, there are two versions of functions, take which is more suitable to you.

[image]

The whole flow will looks like this:
[image]

*This is very easy manual created in few minutes. If you need more information or make some easy Flow just contact me and we can do something via TeamViewer.*

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I will try it tomorrow morning and let you know how it goes

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. You can give me vote now and close tomorrow :)